# Ubuntu 14.04 and 15 possibly incompatible with MSI 970 SB950 motherboard

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2

I tried loading both Ubuntu 14.04LTS and 15 onto a new build. I tried booting through both the grub and that weird back door method. Both didn't work. I got a black screen with some errors. Is this a known bug? I really prefer Linux to Windows, ideas?

Comment: And the errors are ... ??? black screen more likely to be a problem with video card rather the mobo

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the AMD 970 but I did have a similar problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and AMD A10-7700K (mobo is A88XM-A, with Radeon 7 graphics).

Screen worked at the BIOS level (I tried tweaking many settings there) but every boot into 14.04 resulted in various errors plus black screen.

After a week of battling, I gave up and tried 14.10 and hey presto everything worked; I'm now on 15.04 and everything is still good.

So there are bugs in 14.04/3.13 kernel that affect at least some AMD processors. The later kernels (14.10/3.16, 15.04/3.19) fixed my problems.